# UserProfile missing the User object

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using a custom sign up form with django-allauth.

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'project.userprofile.form.UserSignupForm'
```

form.py

```
from django import forms
from models import UserProfile

class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mobile_number',)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)

User.profile = property(lambda u: UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=u)[0])
```

The `User` and the `UserProfile` objects are created, however the UserProfile isn't associated with any User object. It's late and I'm probably missing something silly, right?

***UPDATE***: *As Kevin pointed out, the solution was to add the save method in the form.py. This is how it looks now:*

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from models import UserProfile

class UserSignupForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('mobile_number',)

    def save(self, user):
        profile = UserProfile(user=user)
        profile.mobile_number = self.cleaned_data['mobile_number']
        profile.save()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) says:

> [`ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS`] should implement a ‘save’ method, accepting the newly signed up user as its only parameter.

It looks like you haven't provided such a method, so the user never gets connected to the profile. And I think you're not seeing an error because `ModelForm` has a `save(commit=True)` method that happens to match this signature, even though it doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! It worked for me I'll update my question.

Comment: @henriquea: Great, happy to help. The only thing to note is that you probably shouldn't try to use that `ModelForm` in other contexts, since your `save()` method is now shadowing `ModelForm.save()`. I just filed a [ticket](https://github.com/pennersr/django-allauth/issues/528) at django-allauth suggesting that the name be changed.

Comment: Well pointed Kevin! I'll look for another alternative then. Cheers!